# How can I create a customized facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I want to like an application or a page upon the click of a button. This button has an image and my own css. Now when I clikc on it, I want to trigger the like of an application..
How do I achieve this ? Any reference ...

Comment: Position the facebook iframe on top of your button, and hide it by setting it's opacity to 0.

Comment: are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3493171/534790