# How do I change the colour of 'and one other person like this' when I've added it to my site?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

I'm implementing the facebook like and send buttons into my page but their generate only offers 2 pre-set colours none of which are ideal. I've tried to overwrite the CSS by pointing directly at the element but as their styling is held elsewhere and within such a multi-levelled structure it's proving difficult.

Any thoughts on how I may overwrite the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are tricks to accomplish this (using the inline xml fb tags or using clickjacking techniques), it's unadvicable to do this, as facebook is actively trying to prevent this. The reason for this is that a malicious site could redesign the facebook like button to look like a "next page" button (which is being done on some sites) that way tricking the user into liking their page. In other words, if you try to do this, there is a realistic chance the styling will randomly break every few weeks/months.

Comment: Thanks for this extra information, extremely helpful. Didn't realise it was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this thread: [Custom skin for facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493117/custom-skin-for-facebook-like-button)

Also, make sure that doing so is legal. You never know what a little mistake like that can bring you!

Good luck!