# Change size of I like button

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have to add a biger "i like" button to my webpage due to design requirements and i'm turning nuts, i tried this method: http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/ but it works as long as you are doing a equal size button (or i'm doing something wrong, wich is quite posible :P), otherways is just clickable the area were the original facebook button is.

So is it posible to change the size? i understand that facebook allows you (acording to their policy) change the size, but not the look of it, but i don't see any way to do it.

Comment: That website you linked to is full of crap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493117/custom-skin-for-facebook-like-button

Comment: Sorry Jake, i found this webpage here and doesn't appear anything to me, but i have a addon that blocks all the popups and i don't noticed. Thanks Matthew, sadly the webpage is offline by now, so i can't try it since you need to regist the domain to work with fblm, as soon as i will have it online i will try to do it :).